# Cannot load css and javascript in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

Im using bootstrap as template in my project. When Im trying to access bootstrap in codeigniter, the page cannot load css and javascript. I have added url in autoload.php `$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','html');`

and link in the template and css file like this `<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/member/plugins/chartist-js/dist/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

here is the directory where css and the other file exsist : https://www.dropbox.com/s/mk8tmylkbl106ep/gmbr.png?dl=0

Comment: What have you set $config['base_url'] to? A quick check is to view your HTML from your browser - right click - View Source and examine the links to your CSS etc...

Comment: you can use chrome devtool and view source see your url path get correct or not

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your controller

$this->load->helper('url');